# Check variable typing with typing expression?

Tags: python, typing

Since `Python 3.5` we can use the `typing` module:

```
import typing
foo = []  # type: typing.List[str]
foo.append('bar')
```

Is there a way to use the `typing` syntax to verify a variable?

For example:

```
foo = ['bar']
assert check_typing(foo, typing.List[str])  # True
```

Comment: take a look at [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

Comment: why do you need this type checking?

Comment: AFAIK `typing` module is for type hints, not for type checks

Comment: My goal is to simplify my unit testing when i want to ensure function return type. I will take a look at mypy i use it as external program, maybe can i call it in my code.

Comment: @bux What's wrong with `isinstance`?

Comment: @Georgy: you cannot use complex typings as `isinstance` argument

Comment: @bux: try 2 assertions: check if returned object is `list` like `isinstance(value, list)`, then check if all elements are `str` objects: `all(isinstance(element, str) for element in value)`

Comment: Yes i can make this but it is just one example. I would like use the power of typing. But it seems not possible.